# delay IOS Permission dialogue cordova-plugin-fcm Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

I am evaluating **cordova-plugin-fcm** to send push notifications for Android and iOS. when we try to launch the app with this plugin in IOS, asks for a permission.
I wish I could delay this permission dialogue to a custom action rather than on launch
Is there any option available something similar to `phonegap-plugin-push.init()` method in **cordova-plugin-fcm** ?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, June 14, 2017, there is a pull-request in the cordova-plugin-fcm GitHub repository for this very feature.

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

You could fork this and build in the pull-requests, or wait for the author (who may, or may not, do it).